# Install Office 2003 professional over Office 2003 Basic?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2003

I have a problem with one of our PCs. I've inherited this PC and it's always had MS Office Basic on it. The time has come to install our Access application on it, so I'm trying to install Office Professional 2003.

The problem I have is the installer says the license key is invalid. I can only assume this is down to the fact that the PC used to have Office Basic installed. I've deleted the registration keys for the OFFICE11 section of the registry, but am still getting the problem.

Any suggestions as to how to kill any trace of the old install would be appreciated - it's no longer showing up in the add/remove programs window.

Comment: Fdisk Format Reinstall (doo dah, doo dah) - the only way to be sure you got rid of all traces

Comment: @Broam: Correction: Disk... Management format reinstall (doo dah, doo dah)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a License Key is Invalid error while trying to install, then the serial number you use to install is not a Microsoft Office Proffesional serial number, or it is for a different type of Office (MLK) or some other type of office. Ensure your using the right license key with the right office suite

Comment: It's the same serial number I've always used with this Office installer... I remember how much it cost me, so it gets religiously removed and re-installed every time I change PCs; Just to check, I've just tried installing it on my domestic PC which uses Open Office, and that accepted the serial number - most weird..

Comment: wow... that is really weird...

Comment: You might want to ask this in  superuser.com